# Inheritance of env variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I need to retrieve the env variable `$PS1` of the parent process (the shell) that calls the python program. `$PS1` doesn't belong to `os.environ` inside the python process and `sys.ps1` stores its own prompt.

How can we pass this variable to the program from the shell ?

I invoke the program with : `python3 program.py` from the shell.

Comment: Only an interactive shell knows the value of `$PS1`. Show us how you are invoking the python script from shell

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, the shell from which I call the python program, knows `$PS1`

Comment: Did you try `python3 -i program.py`?

Comment: I don't have access to `$PS1` of the shell. If my prompt on the shell is `prompt$`and I invoke `python3 program.py` I want to get `$PS1`= `prompt$` inside python program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python script can access all the environment variables through `os.environ`. Your problem is that `PS1` is not an environment variable, but only a *local* variable of the shell.

That means that the shell does not pass it to its child in the environment (you can control that by typing `env` or `printenv` in your shell). So unless you manually put it in the environment before starting Python (`export PS1` for sh or bash) you cannot get it in your Python script.

Comment: a local variable of the shell, Agreed. But not all shells started will have visibility to `PS1`, only the interactive ones

Comment: @Inian: my Posix shell on FreeBSD has a local PS1 whether started interactively or not. But none of its child can know it.

Comment: I know you can use `env MYVAR=value child_cmd` to pass a local variable to the child, but how does `printenv` pass a local variable to the child?

Answer (score 1):

If value assigned to `$PS1` doesn't change during runtime of your `program.py` then probably the best option is to pass it as an argument and retrieve it in you script using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html). If the value is changing during runtime, then one of the options would be to store it in some temporary file and read it from there.